# Why is copying a stream and then deserializing using a BinaryFormatter faster than just deserializing

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, stream, deserialization

This code takes about 8 seconds with a stream containing about 65K coming from a blob in a database

```
private string[] GetArray(Stream stream)
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    object result = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    return (string[])result;
}
```

This code takes a few milliseconds:

```
private string[] GetArray(Stream stream)
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    Copy(stream, memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    object result = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    return (string[])result;
}
```

Why?

Comment: What sort of stream do you pass in?

Comment: It's the stream I get from oracleReader.GetOracleBlob(col) or          sqlDataReader.GetSqlBytes(col).Stream. It behaves the same.  The oracle implementation is somewhat faster than for sql server.

Comment: Use a profiler. I suspect bad measurement. Maybe the first primes the cache so the 2nd is fast. Switch the order. Also, take the database out of the equation.

Comment: I ran the profiler.  It shows the same results, even if the times are a little different.  It is not a caching issue.  Retries are equally slow.  If I take the database out of the equation the problem disappears.

Comment: Check the Output window for the slow version, see any "First chance exception" messages?  BinaryFormatter likes to use Stream.Seek(), not supported by the SQL byte streamer for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you say the problem disappears when the database is taken out of the equation. Here is my theory:

`BinaryFormatter` reads from the stream in tiny increments. It *has* to read as little as possible so that it does not accidentally swallow a few bytes *after* the serialized object. That means it is issuing *tons* of read commands (I verified this with Reflector).

Probably, every read of the blob stream is causing a network roundtrip (or some other major overhead). That gives you millions of roundtrips if using `BinaryFormatter` right away.

Buffering first causes the network to be utilized more efficiently because the read buffer size is much bigger.

Comment: I tried setting the buffersize to 1 in the Copy method and sure enough, it was very slow again.  So it seems your theory is correct.  Good to get an answer, thanks a lot.